# h5py install on windows cannot open hdf5dll18.lib and hdf5_hldll.lib

Tags: python, h5py

After downloading [hdf5-1.8.12-win32-vs10shared.zip](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/bin/windows/hdf5-1.8.12-win32-vs10shared.zip) and installing (adds dir to PATH) there is still no hdf5dll18.lib and hdf5_hldll.lib available. So

> python3 setup.py install

fails (python3 is my rename). My h5py is from github.

Workaround:

Copying hdf5.lib and hdf5_hl.lib to the root of the h5py clone and renaming to the wanted files helped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of compiling oneself (e.g. by using the workaround mentioned in the question) there are windows binaries of h5py and many other python packages [available online](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), also for the newest python version.